# "ImportError: No module named xhaus" Python module importing error from ansible

Tags: python, jython, ansible

I have one python script it was working if I run from my terminal directly, but the same script I am running using Ansible but at the time I am getting below error.

Ansible command is:

```
- name: run installer command 2
  command: "{{auto_inst_loc}}/installer.py -i -s -c"
  register: command_result2
- debug: msg="{{command_result2.stdout}}"
- debug: msg="{{command_result2.stderr}}"
```

And command_result2.stderr is

```
"msg": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  
File \"../scripts/Lib/soa/automation/containerManager.py\", line 9, in 
<module>\n    from apicontainer import constants, common\n  File 
\"/opt/akana_sw/sm8/scripts/Lib/soa/automation/apicontainer/common.py\", 
line 10, in <module>\n    from com.xhaus.jyson import JysonCodec as 
json\nImportError: No module named xhaus"
```

Please help me to resolve this.

Edit: Actually forgotten to say, the missing module(xhaus) is a JAR file and it is located in the same path where python script file is located. Is anywhere I need to add that JAR to CLASSPATH?

Comment: Try it with `shell` module instead of `command`. If no luck, investigate the difference between user/ansible environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I had fixed above problem with a little bit hack. I had simply added sys.path.append('JAR location') line in my python script. Boom, its worked pretty well. Please let me know, if anyone know better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I personally try to use it and it work well, can you try this one:

```
- name: Execute the script
  script: "/Path-to-local-system/installer.py -i -s -c"
```

play with it and adjust the parameters, refere this [page](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/script_module.html) for more help

Comment: In your answer you had mentioned 'Path-to-local-system' it means you are saying me to give 'Absolute path' right? and also I had updated question please check once.

Comment: And script module is first trying to move script from local node to remote node but I had already moved that script file with zip(using unarchive module).